# Express JS - Load data asynchronously from a REST endpoint on a web call on Application startup

Tags: node.js, express

I have a middleware called loadDataStartup.js that has a loadData function that calls a REST endpoint to retrieve some JSON data.

./db/loadDataStartup.js

```
'use strict';

const db_contants = require('./db_contants');

function loadData () {
    console.log("*** loadData() called");
    db_contants.getEquipmentCategory()
    .then(function(result_ec) {
        if (typeof result_ec === "object") {
            var equipmentCategoryArr = result_ec["results"];
            console.log("*** equipmentCategoryArr:" + equipmentCategoryArr);
            return db_contants.getLifeExpectancy();
        }
        else
            return JSON.stringify({ "Error": String(result_ec) });      
    }).catch((err) => {
        return JSON.stringify(err);
    })
}

module.exports = {loadData};
```

In my app.js, I want to set the loaded data to an application-level variable called "dataOnStartup" by `app.set`. Such that the variable can later retrieved by `app.get` in the req-res circle.

app.js

```
const { loadData } = require('./db/loadDataStartup');
app.set('dataOnStartup', loadData());
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  console.log("*** dataOnStartup:" + app.get('dataOnStartup'));
  res.locals.session = req.session;
  next();
});
```

However every time a req was sent the console printed `*** dataOnStartup:undefined`. I guess it was the aynchronous thing that caused the problem. But how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using the new async/await syntax ?
app.set('dataOnStartup', await loadData());

Comment: Thanks @OmerShukar. I haven't tried that yet. I think I have to stick to the Promise way as there will be a lot more work to do if you change the backend codes to the async/await method.